# SDHC microSD card and SPI initialization

Tags: spi

I have a 32 GB Kingston SDHC microSD card which has to communicate to [MSP430F2618](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430F2xx_Series) via [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus). I was not able to initialize it by using CMD55 + ACMD41 (with bit30 set to 1), as it is described in SD specification paper. What works is this sequence:

```
  CMD0, arg: 0         , CRC: 0x95 (response:0x01)
  CMD8, arg: 0x1AA     , CRC: 0x87 (response:0x01)
  CMD1, arg: 0x40000000, CRC: 0xFF (response:0x00)
```

I tried it also with a 8 GB SanDisk card and works for that too. So actually, I am using CMD1 here, not ACMD41, with HCS bit set to 1. However, it is not stable, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. This may be about hardware.

Is it not strange that cards are responding to CMD1 with argument `0x40000000`?

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't use `CMD1` to initialize SDHC cards; as said in the SD Card specification:

> In any of the cases CMD1 is not recommended because it may be difficult for the host to distinguish between MultiMediaCard and SD Memory Card.

Some controllers (newer and higher capacity cards mostly) will simply stay in IDLE if you issue `CMD1` to them.
You should first issue `CMD8 0x1AA` after the reset (`CMD0`), and then use `CMD55 + ACMD41`.

*tl;dr* to initialize the card you should:

1. `CMD0` arg: `0x0`, CRC: `0x95` (response: `0x01`)
2. `CMD8` arg: `0x000001AA`, CRC: `0x87` (response: `0x01`)
3. `CMD55` arg: `0x0`, CRC: any (`CMD55` being the prefix to *every* `ACMD`)
4. `ACMD41` , arg: `0x40000000`, CRC: any
5. if response: `0x0`, you're OK; if it's `0x1`, goto 3.

Note that most cards *require* steps 3/4 to be repeated, usually once, i.e. the actual sequence is `CMD0`/`CMD8`/`CMD55`/`ACMD41`/`CMD55`/`ACMD41` - to be sure, try it `n` times (select `n` within your reason), and assume fail if it doesn't.

Also, note that you should assert S̲S̲ (aka CS) low *at* least before and after `CMD0` - and, in reality, probably always when sending any command to the SD card.